# Include external JS file and setting variable

Tags: javascript, parameters

I need to include an external JS-file with

```
<script src="/IframeHelper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I need to set a variable and I tried somthing like this:

```
<script src="/IframeHelper.js" type="text/javascript">var $Vari = 'Para';</script>
```

And inside the "IFrameHelper.js" something like this:

```
var $Site = 'Rootfolder' + $Vari;
```

But you know...this doesn´t work. But how can I do this? It´s a little bit like calling a script with parameters. But such a parameter can be a JSON-String oder "long text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to include `IframeHelper.js` file after you declare your variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $Vari = 'Para';</script>
<script src="/IframeHelper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: yes agree, need to load variable before loading the script, so comes in scope

Comment: Thanks...this works! The other thing I´ve tried now is to call a function in a seperate script-tag after including the file.